# Python - os.path.normpath, but leaving the slashes intact

Tags: python, operating-system

I want to create a Python function that will simultaneously:

- normalize a path
- leave the slashes intact

```py
def rawnorm(path: str) -> str:
    """
    Normalizes path, leaving the slashes intact.

    Args:
        path: File path.
    """
    slashes = "\\", "/"
    # ?????
    return path
```

What I want to achieve:

```py
>>> import os
>>>
>>> os.path.normpath(r"a\b\c\..\d/e\f\g\..\h/i"
'a\\b\\d\\e\\f\\h\\i'
>>> 
>>> # I want this
>>> rawnorm(r"a\b\c\..\d/e\f\g\..\h/i")
'a\\b\\d/e\\f\\h/i'
```

How can I do it? I am certainly sure that there is a built-in function for this somewhere, but I cannot find it apparently.

Comment: Should `'a/b/..\\c'` become `'a/c'`, or `'a\\c'`?

Comment: @user2357112 `'a\\c'`